# getting the window.hash value and add it to attribute class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I am trying to get the window.hash value and trying to add on the clicked element it might be a class or id.

**Example :**

> www.google.com/#navid=12100138+4294957236**

**step 1.** as per above URL "navid" I'm storing in variable.

```
var a = location.hash;
```

**step 2.** I'm removing the "#" and storing only the value (**navid=12100138+4294957236**)

```
$("#search-refine-bar").click(function(e){
  hashValue = location.hash;
    if (hashValue && $.trim(hashValue).length > 0) {
        $(this).attr("class", hashValue.substring(1)); // here I'm trying to add id /class from the has value 
        window.location.hash = hashValue;
            //$(this).removeAttr("id");
        }
    });
```

**step 3 :** the value which I got i.e., **"navid=12100138+4294957236"** this has to be added in the clicked element either it should be id / class.

For example : if I click on 'p' tag hash to be an id / class.

Appreciate your help:-)

Comment: so what is your question actually????

Comment: Don't you mean `.addClass()` rather than `.attr('class',xxxx)`?

Comment: @Kartikeya, getting the hash value and adding it an element with the help of id or class

Comment: @DevlshOne, Thanks let me give a try, but the class name should be the hash value.

Comment: @syd If you continue to have problems with modifying classes and IDs, which is possible since you're obviously working with an established DOM, you may want to consider using `.data()`. Of course, you'll have to be sure that all clients are using an appropriate browser.

Comment: I can't figure out why you're setting `window.location.hash = hashValue;`

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).attr("class",value)` will replace all the existing classes.

You can use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) instead.

```
$("#search-refine-bar").click(function(e){
  hashValue = location.hash;
  if (hashValue && $.trim(hashValue).length > 1) { // it shouldn't be empty after removing #
    $(this).addClass(hashValue.substring(1)); // or  $(this).attr("id",hashValue.substring(1))
    window.location.hash = hashValue;
  }
});
```

*Side note: if you're going to apply the handler on more than one element then it is safer to use classes otherwise you're end up with multiple elements with same `id`, which is invalid*